Webpack not generating chunks for React.lazy imports with babel & react native web
I'm working on a React native web project (with custom Webpack config) and using React.lazy with dynamic imports for code splitting. However, Webpack isn't generating separate chunks for these imports as expected. I've tried several solutions, but none have resolved the issue.
Code:
const Apple = React.lazy(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Apple" */ './Apple'));

Webpack config:
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');

const config = (_, argv) => ({
    target: 'web',
    entry: {
        main: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'main'),
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
        alias: {
            'react-native$': 'react-native-web',
        },
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(tsx|jsx|ts|js)?$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        cacheDirectory: true,
                        presets: [
                            ['@babel/preset-env', { modules: false }], // Transpile modern JS
                            '@babel/preset-react', // JSX support
                            'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
                        ],
                        plugins: [
                            'react-native-web',
                            '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
                            '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from',
                            'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
                            '@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types',
                            [
                                '@babel/plugin-transform-private-methods',
                                { loose: true },
                            ],
                        ],
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index.html'),
        }),
        process.env.ANALYZE && new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
    ].filter(Boolean),
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all',
            cacheGroups: {
                vendor: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: 'vendors',
                    chunks: 'all',
                },
            },
        },
    },
});

module.exports = config;

My final chunks are:
Assets: 
  main.d4d5a64793bc974cb170.js (2.05 MiB)
  vendors.e9f736b3a31c46ef0971.js (9.08 MiB)
Entrypoints:
  main (11.1 MiB)
      vendors.e9f736b3a31c46ef0971.js
      main.d4d5a64793bc974cb170.js

